# System.Windows.Forms.Timer is NOT Firing Tick Event Inside Foreach Block

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

I have a System.Windows.Forms.Timer associated with my main form.  I need this timer to fire every 1000ms so that some work can be performed.  The Timer.Enabled property is set to true in the Form.Shown event and the interval is set to 1000.

The Timer.Tick event does fire about every second for the most part.  However, the Tick events stop firing when my application is executing a foreach statement.  I have tried Thread.Sleep but, that did not help.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  The code that handles my Timer.Tick event is wrapped with exception handling and I have verified that the event stops firing in the debugger during execution of the foreach block.  Additionally, my application is not multi-threaded at this time.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Please, post the code.

Comment: If you are keeping the UI thread busy in a loop, then no, the timers `Tick` handler won't be able to execute. If you have a long running loop, push it onto a background thread. `Sleep` won't help because that also blocks the UI thread. There are other timers that don't fire on the UI thread (System.Timer), but if your tick needs access to the UI, then that won't actually help you if the UI thread is still busy.

Comment: Multi-thread your application now...

Comment: Thanks, I'll re-factor to use a background thread.  I knew that I was probably doing something stupid.  If you post your answer Matt Burland, I'll accept the answer in a little while.

Comment: `Application.DoEvents` in your loop will help but it is a cheap fix.  You could do with executing the loop in another thread as it is currently blocking the UI thread from executing and that is where the tick event is happening. A Background worker may help you do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are keeping the UI thread busy in a loop, then no, the timers Tick handler won't be able to execute. If you have a long running loop, push it onto a background thread. Sleep won't help because that also blocks the UI thread. There are other timers that don't fire on the UI thread (System.Timer), but if your tick needs access to the UI, then that won't actually help you if the UI thread is still busy.

Comment: This pointed me to the right direction but I had to use System.Threading.Timer because System.Timer was still sometimes not firing the Elapsed event

Answer (score 2):

Implementation of the System.Timers.Timer might look something like this:

```
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000; // every second
timer.Elapsed += TimerTick;

...

private void TimerTick(object state, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // do some work here
    Thread.Sleep(500);

    var reportProgress = new Action(() => 
    {  
        // inside this anonymous delegate, we can do all the UI updates
        label1.Text += string.Format("Work done {0}\n", DateTime.Now);
    });
    Invoke(reportProgress);
}
```